# What is difference between deselectRowAtIndexPath and cell setSelected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

What is difference between

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

and

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
 [cell setSelected:NO];
```

???

Comment: You must be new Dan; downvoting happens all over for no reason other than ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a UITableView a cell does not match a specific piece of your data. It can (and should most of the time) be reused and it is nil when not visible.

`deselectRowAtIndexPath` will set the indexPath as 'not selected' in your tableview, so when you scroll back and forth to that cell, it will stay unselected, because you told your tableview that whatever the cell you display at that indexPath it should be unselected.

With `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
[cell setSelected:NO];` you set the cell as unselected. However that cell can be used for other pieces of data, and it can even be nil if this indexPath is not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

First one is programmatically deselecting the cell. So it will un-highlight the cell if the user has selected it already.

As for the second bit of code, I believe that is just a pointer or reference to one of the cells in your table view. You can use this code to edit a cell OUTSIDE of any of the table view delegate methods. So if you wanted to edit/update a label on one of your cells but from a random method (not a table view delegate method), then you could use that code to reference the label text property.

I think you should also check out the Apple Developer Library website. It explains all the different table view method/properties/etc in lots of detail:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/

Answer (score 0):

The concepts of "selected" is different for a tableview and for a cell.  The tableview can have one or more rows selected that changes the state of the tableview, however changing the tableview cell selected state only affects its appearance and nothing else.